# How can I create an event with a dataTransfer property?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to write a test that checks that my dragstart event listener sets properties on e.dataTransfer.

I can manually create and dispatch a MouseEvent:

```
var event = new MouseEvent('dragstart');
html[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

but event.dataTransfer is null so I'm getting null reference exceptions.

I've tried manually setting the property:

```
event.dataTransfer = {};
```

and I've tried setting the property using a property descriptor:

```
var event = new MouseEvent('dragstart');
Object.defineProperty(event, "dataTransfer", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value : {}
});
```

but neither has worked.

Comment: It seems you should create a [`DragEvent`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/DragEvent), not a `MouseEvent`.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw this on MDN too but I couldn't seem to actually create one: DragEvent is not defined

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I can't remember but I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
var dataTransferObj = { setData: function (val) { this.data = val }}
var event = new CustomEvent('dragover');
event.dataTransfer=dataTransferObj
target.dispatchEvent(event);
```